# I want to assign value in input masking

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use the **"vue-the-mask"** library to mask the input. When I want to assign a value via ID, it does not write the relevant value. How can I solve this problem?

HTML

```
<ua-mask :id="'gsm-'+index" :mask="['##########']" placeholder="GSM Number"></ua-mask>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("gsm-"+index).value = text.phoneNumber;
```

Comment: Why not use `v-model` instead? If you can't for some reason, u need to put your js part in  vue's mounted lifecycle. Otherwise the referance 'gsm-'+index is not initialized yet :)

Comment: You need to use Vue to change reactive values, not raw JavaScript.  I suggest reading the [Vue guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) to learn the basics